# How do I code in for the user to set their own seed

Tags: python, python-3.x, random-seed

I've been programming a game for about a week now and I've got a good chunk of the basic code in, where I'm stuck however is how do I make it so that the player can set their own seed using random.seed, after looking around a bit I couldn't find any way to actually do this, I was thinking of putting a variable into it like random.seed(variable) but that just uses the word as the seed, am I on the right track with this or am I way far off the mark? Sorry if this is really easy to some people, but I'm still kind of new to python

Answer (score 0):

This is a (really) short program that prints 50 random numbers from 0 to 100, taking the seed as the first argument:

```
import random
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    random.seed(sys.argv[1])

for _ in range(0, 50):
    print(random.randint(0, 100))
```

Then from the command line:

```
python3 myscript.py 1
```

That will print a consistent set or random numbers for any number you supply.

A more "customizable" version that also includes argument parsing:

```
import argparse
import random
import sys


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--seed')
parser.add_argument('--count', default=50, type=int)
parser.add_argument('--max-value', default=100, type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.seed:
    random.seed(args.seed)

for _ in range(0, args.count):
    print(random.randint(0, args.max_value))
```

NOTE: It is preferable to use an `int` as the argument for `random.seed`, but `random.seed` will also take an arbitrary string and "numberize" it for purposes of getting to a number that will be used for a seed. It sounds like for your purposes, this default behavior is actually fine, so might as well take advantage of it.